# Checking if file exist in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have password protected website without password, i have a dream then the website will check "does your computer **containt file acess.txt**,if this file contains 123456,website do ok you have an acess and redirects you to index.html

I hosting my website in **Node.js**
And i also running on Linux Debian

Apologie for my English, **im Czech and young**.
and yes im a programmer.

Comment: Browsers by default due to security reasons cannot access files in client computer. JavaScript via Node can read a file in server, but thats not you want right?

Comment: A valid question if albeit extremely coarse from the lack of experience. You *can* do this if you want (and have the justification for) though not in the context of which you're thinking.

Answer (score 1):

> does your computer containt file acess.txt,if this file contains 123456,website do ok you have an acess

You can't do that without having the user manually pick that file from an `input type="file"` or drag-and-drop it into your web page. For security reasons, web pages cannot check for files they provide the path of.

> and redirects you to index.html

That would mean your site is completely insecure anyway — anyone could just go directly to `index.html`.

All access checks must happen on the **server**, not the client (browser).

Comment: There *has* to be a dupetarget for this though... Please ping me if you find a good one.

Comment: ActiveX would work too, but I don't recommend this

Comment: @Cid - ActiveX in browsers is very, *very* dead. :-)

Comment: unfortunately, still used in some companies :(

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

Replace:

```
<input name="post_password" type="password" value="" />
```

With:

```
<input name="post_file" type="file" value="" />
```

However you can *not* have JavaScript go snooping through a person's file system. They must choose to browser and select a file to upload and then submit the form.